# Ionic.Zip Complete Extract C#

Tags: c#

Olá estou usando o using Ionic.Zip; e esta extraindo certo porem no final quando ele terminar de extrair preciso apagar o arquivo ZIP q ele estava extraindo e não estou vendo função para identificar quando ele termina de extrair os arquivos, alguém já passou por isso e tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso ?

O que tentei foi :

```
 private void Zip_ExtractProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        double dFalta = ((e.TotalBytesToTransfer - e.BytesTransferred) / 1024);
        lbCompletoExtrair.Text = "Extraindo dados : " + dFalta.ToString();
        lbCompletoExtrair.Refresh();
        if (dFalta == 0)
        {
            lbSair.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Mas não deu certo ele as vezes não entra no if.

Comment: Não seria a questão de você verificar de todos os os bytes já foram transferidos?
`if (e.TotalBytesToTransfer <= 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Olá Obrigado pela resposta, resolvi da seguinte forma,

```
double dTotalBytesParaTransferir = e.TotalBytesToTransfer;
double dTotalBytesTransferidos = e.BytesTransferred;
if (dTotalBytesParaTransferir == dTotalBytesTransferidos)
{

}
```